# Angular 2+ resuable component

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-mvc

Recently I been developing some reusable UI components in Angular 4. Intent is that these components should be available from a CDN and these can be used in any Asp.net or Java web applications. When ever there is any change in the components changes should be available to the consumer applications without any changes or compilation of the consumer applications.

E.g I have created header, footer and sidebar component using angular 4 app. I hosted the app bundle on web server(IIS).

In another application (MVC core) I am referencing these bundles (*.js) files and all the components  header, footer is rendering perfectly.

Problem: 
As part of the Angular application I have also developed some services which communicate to the components from the MVC-Core application using some get and set method angular service calls. I am not able to access these services, rather I would say don't know how to inject these services/modules in MVC application typescript code from a compiled ES5 code when the code is hosted on the web server. 
I might be doing some stupid mistake as I am kind of new to angular 4.

Sample code inside body tag:

```
     <!-- Top Navbar -->
        <my-header></my-header>
        <!-- /Top Navbar -->
        <!--  Sidebar -->
        <my-navsidebar></my-navsidebar>
        <!-- / Sidebar -->
        <!-- Main Content -->
        <section class="content-wrap">
            <!-- Breadcrumb -->
            <!--<asr-breadcrumb ></asr-breadcrumb>-->
            <!-- /Breadcrumb -->
            @RenderBody()
        </section>
        <!-- /Main Content -->
        <!-- Search Bar -->
        <my-searchbar></my-searchbar>

        <!-- /Search Bar -->
        <!-- Chat -->
        <my-notificationbar></my-notificationbar>
        <!-- /Chat -->
        <!-- Footer -->
        <my-footer></my-footer>
        <!-- /Footer -->

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://server/dist/main.bundle.js"></script>
```

Footer Component ts file

```
    import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      // tslint:disable-next-line:component-selector
      selector: 'my-footer',
      templateUrl: './templates/footer.html',
      styleUrls: ['./my-footer.component.css']
    })
    export class MyFooterComponent implements OnInit {
      footerDate: any = new Date();
      constructor() {}

      ngOnInit() {}

    }
```

Footer html

```
    <footer class="right-align">{{ footerDate | date :'yyyy'}} 
    <i class="fa fa-copyright"></i> All rights reserved.</footer>
```

One of the service from the angular app:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class MyDataserviceService {

  constructor() { }
  log(){
    console.log('from service');
  }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post one the components in question? In general, your services should be a shared dependency of the CDN hosted components in order to make this sort of thing happen. Also, this has nothing to do with Asp.net or Java

Comment: I totally agree this is not asp.net or Java dependent but i just wanted to clarify that I am trying to use it in dot.net environment.

Answer (score 0):

First, a good approach for your components is to group each on it's own module with all the services the component is using declared into that module. This way, you only have to import the module into the app.module of the new app and they should work.

On the other hand, you did not described what those services are used for, but make sure that your components are not coupled so that you can reuse then as you described as building blocks into other apps.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** this is not Angular specific

Let's say I have a component that is going to be used by several applications. Regardless of delivery mechanism (via CDN or whatever), the first step is to turn these components into separate *packages*.

Practically, a few things characterize a package.

For one, a package is something that you might install via a package manager (such as JSPM, Yarn, or NPM), download from a CDN, or host via an internal, company specific mechanism.

Another critical aspect of a package is that, while it is often not self-sufficient or stand-alone, it describes its own dependencies via a manifest. This is critical because it allows the package to be consumed transparently. For JavaScript packages, this usually means that the package contains a `package.json` file that lists these dependencies, their required semver ranges, and other metadata.

Say you want to take a component, say `search-bar` and make it into a package that can be installed and referenced by multiple applications. Further, imagine that at present `search-bar` is part of one of these applications, and looks as follows

```
// app/components/search-bar.js
import {inject, template} from '@framework/utils';

import SearchService from 'app/services/search-service';

@inject(SearchService)
@template(`<div>....</div>`)
export default class SearchBar {
  constructor(searchService) {
    this.searchService = searchService;
  }
}
```

Now we decide it we want to make it into its own package.

First, we move it out of `app/components` into a new directory, lets call it `packages/search-bar`, that will be conceptually a new and separate project. We add a `package.json` file to this directory (could be something else like `bower.json` but this is just an example). This directory now contains the following

```
package.json
search-bar.js
```

and `package.json` looks like

```
{
  "name": "search-bar",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A shared search bar component used by multiple applications",
  "main": "search-bar.js"
}
```

Now, we hit our first snag, `search-bar` has some dependencies that are external to it. It depends on two decorators in the `utils` part of framework we are using to build our web applications (I have cleverly named this framework *framework*). Thisis easily resolved. We just change our `package.json` to

```
{
  "name": "search-bar",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A shared search bar component used by multiple applications",
  "main": "search-bar.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@framework/utils": "*"
  }
}
```

That is all well and good but then we notice that we also depend on something else. A service that is part of the application that used to contain the newly packagified component itself!

This is where it starts to get complicated. Since we seem to be using a dependency injection system that uses function *references* instead of *strings* to register and inject dependencies, we can't make `search-bar` implicitly depend on `search-service`. This is probably for the best since it is an absolutely terrible practice!

If the only module of our original application that depends on `app/services/search-service` is `search-bar`, then the answer is simple, just move `search-service` into the `search-bar` package we are extracting.

However, if other parts of our application depend on it, we need to create *another* distinct package containing that service. For now, we will content ourselves with just extracting this single service and thus we will end up with something that should look familiar by now

```
{
  "name": "search-service",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A shared search service used by multiple applications",
  "main": "search-service.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@framework/utils": "*"
  }
}
```

elaborating a little, `search-service.js` looks something like

```
// packages/search-service/service-service.js
import {registered} from 'framework/utils';

@registered
export default class SearchService {
  searchFor(searchTerm) {...}
}
```

Now we adjust our `search-bar` package as follows

The `packages/search-bar/package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "search-bar",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A shared search bar component used by multiple applications",
  "main": "search-bar.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@framework/utils": "*",
    "search-service": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

and the `packages/search-bar/search-bar.js` file:

```
import {inject, template} from '@framework/utils';

// We are now importing from the name of our extracted shared search-service package!
import SearchService from 'search-service';

@inject(SearchService)
@template(`<div>....</div>`)
export default class SearchBar {
  constructor(searchService) {
    this.searchService = searchService;
  }
}
```

After the above restructuring, the `package.json` of your original application will now list `"search-service"` and `"search-bar"` as dependencies.

That is the general idea. Now that the packages are standalone, each listing their own dependencies (which in reality will likely be more intricate) they can be built, published, and deployed separately.

**Note:** This is a good opportunity to consider the architecture of the application at large, for example we may want to extract several services or components into a single shared package.

Comment: Aluan, appreciate your detailed answer. These things i will take into consideration before creating a the final product. But in this scenario also I want to know how to import the module which i created in this package and this package i want to host on the server; i don't want to use npm, i don't want it to embed or use as local module for the consuming application.